# access private enum in Java

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have the following Java Enum:

```
enum IssueMap {

  ISSUE_TYPE,

  public static .... getIssueTypes(String IssueName) {
    
    return ...;
  }

}
```

*Notice that I don't have public keyword in front of a enum!*

I want to call this code into JUnit test like this:

```
  @Test
  public void genericTest() {
    ....... = IssueMap.getIssueTypes(....);
    assertNotNull(...);
  }
```

I get error `'com.IssueMap' is not public in 'com....'. Cannot be accessed from outside package`

I can't change the original enum code. Is there some solution with reflection for example to access the enum code?

Comment: Place the test in the same package as the enum.

Comment: Put your unit test in the package “com”

Comment: enums are package-private per default. Therefore the suggestion from @JustanotherJavaprogrammer should work.

Comment: What is ' public intron'? And if you want access from outside, why is it private?

Comment: how is `IssueMap.getIssueTypes(....)` used by your code? The enum not public, in other words, it's an implementation detail encapsulated in a bigger usecase. For example, if `ServiceX` uses these issues types when implementing `methodY`, maybe it's enough to only test `ServiceX.methodY()`.

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir it's called into the same package

Comment: @PeterPenzov but it has to be called by some public method eventually, even if this method is part of a different class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IssueMap enum is not private, but rather [package-private](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). If your test class is in the same package name as your IssueMap enum then your test class should be able to access the IssueMap enum without changing the IssueMap enum

```
package com.myenum;

enum IssueMap {

  ISSUE_TYPE,

  public static .... getIssueTypes(String IssueName) {
    
    return ...;
  }

}
```

```
package com.myenum;

class IssueMapTest {
  @Test
  public void genericTest() {
    ....... = IssueMap.getIssueTypes(....);
    assertNotNull(...);
  }
}
```

Notice the package name in IssueMap and IssueMapTest are the same. Even though my IssueMap path is *src/main/java/com/myenum/IssueMap.java* and IssueMapTest path is *src/test/java/com/myenum/IssueMapTest.java*